# Use Form controls insideof MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to create simple application that on press button sets myLabel to visible

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 myLabel.setVisible(false);
}
```

But compiler claim `'myLabel' was not declared in this scope`

Why and how to fix that?

Comment: Does `myLabel` is a global member of `MainWindow`? maybe you missed adding `ui->myLabel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label is not declared in the scope of the function `on_pushButton_clicked`
this way the compailer claims the 'myLabel' was not declared in this scope.

To solve it you need to declare your label as a global member.

H file

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
       MainWindow(QWidget * poParent);

   private:

       // Declare label as global scope
       QLabel * m_poMyLabel;
       QPushButton * m_poMyButton;

   private slots:
       void on_pushButton_clicked();
}
```

In cpp:

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * poParent):QMainWindow(poParent)
 {
    QHBoxLayout * poLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QWidget * poCentralWidget = new QWidget(this);

    poCentralWidget->setLayout(poLayout);
    this->setCentralWidget(poCentralWidget);
    m_poMyButton = new QPushButton(this);
    m_poMyButton->setText("Hide label");
    m_poMyLabel = new QLabel(this);
    m_poMyLabel->setText("Hello");
    poLayout->addWidget(m_poMyButton);
    poLayout->addWidget(m_poMyLabel);

    connect(m_poMyButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, &MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked);

 }

 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {// Now it should compile and set label visible false
   m_poMyLabel->setVisible(false);
 }
```

Comment: And how to set visible to false in design time?

Comment: @vico what do you mean 'design time'?

Comment: @vico Just create your label in designer, not programatically. You don't need a `QLabel myLabel;` member in code if you already have it in designer.

Comment: @Simon you should declare a label as a pointer, but not as a member, because `addWidget` will call a `setParent` method and you will have a problem with class destruction.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, thank for your notice, I updated my answer.